# Showcase skills without rating

Tags: website-design

I'm looking for examples on how I would go about showcasing my skills without the rating bar/stars/etc... that seem so common now. I'm having a hard time finding examples that showcase skills without a rating. What are some good examples of showcasing skills without rating?

Comment: what is the context here? Is this a personal website? Do you have a mock of the surrounding context / design?

Comment: Yes this would be for a personal site. http://franciscot.me

Comment: Is this ratings that people are leaving for you? As in clients are rating specific skills? And you are accumulating multiple ratings? Is there testimonials?

Comment: More like. An interesting way to display my skills such as (JS, Pythong, etc...) without having those ratings. I'm trying to find examples where it's more than just a list or table essentially.

Comment: I was up late myself last night, apologies. Although I seem to always make that typo with Python :(

Comment: Whenever I've reviewed candidates, I've never trusted software usage ratings. In fact, if someone marks themselves as 'expert' i tend to distrust the rest of their resumé - software move so fast that, by the time you've sent out your details, it's moved on and you have something new to learn. On top of that, The software is so varied. I just want to know if you can use what we have a license for - If you're looking anything above junior level then you should be reasonably competent in any software you put down - if you not then don't list it. No need for ratings at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply write bulletpoints of your skills, seperate them with commas or create a tag type of visualisation like on the attached image.

I hope this helps..

[image: tags]

Comment: Yea that actually looks pretty good.